# Azure Notification HUB with FCM - NullPointerException

Tags: azure, notifications, push

I am trying to register my FCM service with Azure Notification hub.

I am getting a valid FCM token using my Instance Id Service which extends FirebaseMessagingService().

Below is my InstanceIdService which is returning a valid token and starts my registrationIntentService

```
    class FCMInstanceIdService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "FCMInstanceIDService"
    }

    init {
        Log.i(TAG, "init")
    }

    override fun onNewToken(refreshedToken: String?) {

        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().instanceId.addOnSuccessListener { instanceIdResult ->

            instanceIdResult.token

            // Log the event
            Log.i(TAG, "Refreshing GCM Registration Token")

            // Declare our intent to start the service
            val intent = Intent(this, FCMRegistrationIntentService::class.java)
            // Start the service!
            startService(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the portion of code where-in I try to register this token with my notification hub.

```
// Declare the azure notification hub
val notificationHub = NotificationHub(
        // Provide our notification hub name
        CentreMK.FCM_NOTIFICATION_HUB_NAME,
        // Provide our notification hub connection string
        CentreMK.FCM_NOTIFICATION_HUB_LISTEN_CONNECTION_STRING,
        // The context of this service
        this)

// Log the event
Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to register with NH using token : $token")

// Update the registration id by registering our token with the notification hub
// This provides us with the registration id
regID = notificationHub.register(token).registrationId
```

This is the exception I get :

[Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBFaZ.png)

Any help is appreciated cause I dont know how I could possibly get a null pointer exception when I've configured everything correctly.

Answer (score 1):

In your initialisation of the `String HubListenConnectionString`in class:

```
public class NotificationSettings {
   public static String SenderId = "<Your project number>";
   public static String HubName = "<Your HubName>";
   public static String HubListenConnectionString = "<Enter your DefaultListenSharedAccessSignature connection string>";
}
```

you did not add `"Endpoint=sb://"`to the beginning of the string (i.e: `public static String HubListenConnectionString ="Endpoint=sb://......"`. After which you might encounter a "Resource not found" exception error. That's where I am stuck at now.